# mongoose 4.0 connection error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was using mongodb 3.0 and mongoose 4.0 on my windows xp 32 bit os
It does not work for my little project and get an error. I tried to simplify the problem. 
So I did a quick test:

```
express microblog
npm install
```

then in db.js, I put

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test',console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', function (callback) {
  console.log("succesfully connected");
});
```

then I started the mongodb server at port 27017. when I run the db.js, I got something like this:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\test\microblog>node db.js
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
connection error: { [MongoError: connect UNKNOWN] name: 'MongoError', message: '
connect UNKNOWN' }
```

The last line is the same as what I got in my other little project.
I tried to install mongodb2.6, it has the same problem.
The mongodb server works when I use mongo-connection instead of mongoose in the other js file. I tried rebooting the computer, removed the lock file and did the mongod --repair, the problem is still there, please help, thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is WinXP. Newer versions of MongoDB don't support WinXP, and Mongoose use mongodb module as dependency.
Try to use older version of Mongoose, here is my package.json for test application:

```
{
 "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
     "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
 "dependencies": {
 "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
 "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
 "debug": "~2.2.0",
 "ejs": "~2.3.3",
 "express": "~4.13.1",
 "mongoose": "3.8",
 "morgan": "~1.6.1",
 "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
 }
}
```

Version 3.8 of Mongoose uses mongodb v1.4.38 as dependency, and it works just fine on WinXP.